# xcode not recognizing changes to class

Tags: c++, xcode, build, compiler-errors

For some reason, xcode is not recognizing any of the changes I am making to one of the classes in my program (which is a C++ command line program).

For instance, if I create a new method for this class and attempt to use it in another file(which already has the .h file for the class included and I have already made extensive use of the class in that file) it gives me an error saying that member function does not exist. Other changes that don't seem to be updating include when I try to alter one of the class variables.

I've tried cleaning the build, quitting and restarting XCode, removing and readding the class's .cpp file from build phases, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did you update your header file with the additions?

Comment: yes, the header file is where the method is declared and then its implementation is in the .cpp file

Comment: Try posting some of the code. Maybe there's a genuine issue with the code that we can see.

Comment: I'm coming across the same issue, I'll post code when it happens again.

Comment: Try to edit the code in external editor... I've heard that Xcode 9 has problems with saving changes to files