# Xcode 9: not recognizing newly-updated functions

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, linker, xcode9

Found a post ([xcode not recognizing changes to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21946273/xcode-not-recognizing-changes-to-class_)) from a while back asking this same question, although it went unanswered, so here I am.

Here's the gist of things: I made changes to a library, which I then reflected in the header file, but Xcode is only recognizing the old version of the function before I had made any changes.

**Attempt #1**: I assumed it was a linking issue, so I went into my build settings and manually set search paths for library and header files. This, of course, didn't work.

**Attempt #2**: Next I stumbled upon another gem that told me to go into Window->Organizer, which of course didn't work either.

Comment: Whoa! This is painful :P... Have you tried Cleaning the project? Go to Product -> Clean

Comment: Share a code so that we can see and may help you, if your still stuck with it try the previous versions of xcode?

Comment: @ZeMoon Ended up not having to! The problem was idiotic, but would rather that than it be an issue with XCode itself

Comment: @HarjotSingh I would have in the original post if my code had been the issue. Double and triple checked includes and linker paths, all to no avail. Got it solved, though (refer to OP)!

Comment: If you have solved it, then post it as an answer.

Comment: @HarjotSingh Sorry! I had it in the question header, but it was removed by the mods I presume. So apparently XCode wasn't updating the source code of the files I was editing for whatever reason (still don't know exactly why this was happening). When I opened them in Finder instead of XCode and edited them in Sublime, all the changes were saved and I was good to go.

Comment: Good to know your problem is solved.